# Using a derived type pointer and a polymorphic target in Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, gfortran, polymorphism

The Fortran function listed below compiles and executes as expected using ifort 11.1. However GFortran 4.6 returns the compiler error:

> THIS_NML => THIS
>   Error: Different types in pointer assignment at (1); attempted assignment of CLASS(UNIT) to TYPE(UNIT).

Fortran code:

```
FUNCTION PROCESS_COMMAND(THIS, CMD, DATA) RESULT(RET)
   CLASS(UNIT), INTENT(INOUT), TARGET :: THIS
   CHARACTER(LEN = *), INTENT(IN)     :: CMD
   CHARACTER(LEN = *), INTENT(IN)     :: DATA
   CHARACTER(LEN = 200)               :: STRING
   INTEGER                            :: IOS
   TYPE(UNIT), POINTER                :: THIS_NML

   ! CREATE A NAMELIST
   NAMELIST /VARS/ THIS_NML
   THIS_NML => THIS  
   RET = 0
   STRING = '&VARS THIS_NML%' // TRIM(CMD) // ' = ' // TRIM(DATA) // ' /'

   ! READ CMD AND DATA
   READ(STRING, NML=VARS, IOSTAT=IOS)
   RET = IOS

END FUNCTION PROCESS_COMMAND
```

Because namelist's cannot be created using polymorphic objects, the derived type pointer `THIS_NML` is being used to create the namelist. Any ideas how to make this work with GFortran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `select type` construct. Something like

```
select type ( A => THIS )
   type is ( UNIT )
      Here you can treat A as nonpolymorphic variable of type UNIT (if the test is succesful).
end select
```

Comment: Thanks!  This compiles and runs in both gfortran 4.6 and ifort 11.1.