# Fortran: namelist + associate does not work

Tags: fortran, associate

I store parameters in a derived type and I want to load them from a file through a namelist at run time. This is a sketch of the code:

```
module options_definitions
implicit none
type :: opts

integer :: option1
integer :: option2

contains
procedure :: load      => load_options

end type opts

contains

subroutine load_options(this,path_to_profiles_folder,profile_name)

class(opts),      intent(inout) :: this
character(len=*), intent(in)    :: path_to_profiles_folder
character(len=*), intent(in)    :: profile_name 
integer                         :: err, ios
logical                         :: file_exists
character(len=255)              :: err_message
character(len=255)              :: path_to_profile_folder

ASSOCIATE( option1    => this%option1, &
           option2    => this%option2)

namelist /options_nml/ option1, option2

! the following is INESSENTIAL added for completeness
!-----------------------------------------------------
path_to_profile_folder=trim(path_to_profiles_folder)//trim(profile_name)

! load options from the configuration file (namelist set above)
INQUIRE(FILE=trim(path_to_profile_folder)//'/'//trim(opt_file_name), EXIST=file_exists)   ! 'file_exists' will be TRUE if the file exists and FALSE otherwise

if (file_exists) then
   call my_open(111,trim(path_to_profile_folder)//'/'//trim(opt_file_name),&
      'Options module could not open the options configuration file')
   read(111,NML=options_nml,iostat=ios,iomsg=err_message)
   call check_read_success_and_close(111,trim(path_to_profile_folder)//'/'//trim(opt_file_name),ios,err_message,&
      'Options module could not read from the options configuration file')
else
   print*,'Warning: The required configuration file containing options &
      (options.nml) does not exist. The inbuilt options will be &
      used instead.'
endif
!---------------------------------------

end associate

end subroutine load_options
```

The compiler complains that `option1`, `option2`, ... have not been declared ( `(iFort) error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [OPTION1]`).

From the description of the namelist construct (https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-EAC90ABA-859A-4745-B9FC-B8D66B5B6FF0.htm) I read that

> each variable in var-list must be accessed by USE or host association

which I would say is the case here as `this` is a dummy argument with `intent(inout)`. Isn't this the use association?

What is wrong? Is there a workaround such that I don't have to declare the same stuff many times in different places?

(e.g. declaring `option1` as module private and copying it in `this` at the end of the `load_options` routine rather than using the `associate` construct would work but I would prefer something less prone to omissions when adding options later)

Thanks in advance for any comments.

PS: Just before posting I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658305/using-a-derived-type-pointer-and-a-polymorphic-target-in-fortran). The code looks like it could be doing what I want but without seeing the definition of the `unit` type I cannot understand what it does.

EDIT1: Follow up on Vladimir's comments
Now I quite understand what is going on. In the question I linked the author uses a pointer to `this` not to individual fields and this would be my preferred option if I could make it work. When I tried it the compiler was fine with the namelist declaration but refused to read from the input file saying

> error #5498: Allocatable or pointer derived-type fields require a user-defined I/O procedure.
>      read(111,NML=options_nml,iostat=ios,iomsg=err_message)

Any suggestions what such an I/O procedure could look like? I am confused, if it is possible to add a derived-type (or a pointer to it) in a namelist declaration then I would assume that the variables in the input file should be referred to as `this%option1` and that would be it. I have found another discussion [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/278777#comment-1466075) where Steve Lionel from Intel supports this view saying

> The Fortran standard allows only "variable-name" in the namelist object list. You can, however, put T in the namelist and reference T%I in namelist input (and it is shown on output).

But the compiler complains without even seeing the file.

EDIT2: 
What I changed in the code above (that lead to the compiler error in first edit) was this:

```
class(opts), intent(inout), target :: THIS
TYPE(opts), POINTER :: THIS_NML

namelist /options_nml/ THIS_NML
THIS_NML => THIS
```

The associate construct deleted, the original namelist declaration deleted. The error occurred in the `read` statement in the `if (file_exists)` block. So what I did was to use a pointer to a structure in the namelist declaration. That was all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ifort you can actually use the solution from my answer you linked. The exact definition of `unit` is not important there.

```
select type(t => this)
  type is (opts)

    associate( option1    => t%option1, &
               option2    => t%option2)

      namelist /options_nml/ option1, option2

      read...
    end associate
end select
```

This is because `this` is polymorphic in your example.

I investigated, whether this usage is standard conforming, and it is not. Ifort clearly warns, when asked to follow the standard

```
ifort -stand f08  namelist.f90
namelist.f90(8): warning #7775: Placement of NAMELIST statement is non-standard.
```

There are many other workarounds you can do. You can create local pointers and read them in the namelist read, that is exactly what the answer linked by you does. That would compile also with `gfortran`. I would go this way.

```
integer, pointer :: option1, option2

namelist /options_nml/ option1, option2

option1 => this%option1
option2 => this%option2

read...
```

Or use normal local variables and copy the values to `this`.

Comment: Many thanks Vladimir for your enlightening comments. It is now clear why it could not work. I have edited my question with a follow up thought on your comments. Could you please take a look?

Comment: It is not clear to me at all which code produced your new error message. You must show it.

Comment: Ok @PetrH , I see, don't use pointer to `this`, do it as I have shown in my answer, point to the components. It is quite clear, that your actual case is much more complex that what you show, because the code in your question can't produce this error message. Don't expect us to debug a code you don't show.

Comment: Added another edit to clarify the changes in the code. True the code I compile is not exactly the same but is almost identical. But I take your point. Anyway your way of using pointers to individual fields works so I will stick with this for now. Many thanks for help.

Comment: @PetrH The point your actual `type(opt)` seems to be more complicated and contains `allocatable` or `pointer` component. That changes the situation. Anyway, you may want to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I see, you are right there is an allocatable variable in the derived type. Although not intended to appear in the namelist I can see why the compiler doesn't like it. Getting rid off it made it work. Thanks for the hint. It is working now.